# wigdet of a native andorid or ios with cordova and angular not angular js?

Tags: android, ios, angular, cordova

**How can I write a widget of native android or iOS with cordova plugin and angular?**
My problem is how can build native of not native widget my project with angular and cordova for the mobile version ,taking into consideration the widget is a native behavior in ios or android .

I do my research for more *than 1 month*

How can i build a cordova plugins ?
**I had an idea to had two project one for android or ios and one with angular but i can't mutch with each other** .

I know that there is **microsoft plugin** `http://microsoft.github.io/ace/` but it s not *supported since 2016*

I ask alot of people but the answer is the corodova is a view for the mobile app not native we can make plugins but for my problem we can't ..

**so any help and thank you**

Comment: any help please!

Comment: I suggest you check the advice on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you've been doing research for more than 1 month, I encourage you to what research have you tried, what have you found, and what are the blockers you're finding. The Microsoft thing is a great start, but the more effort you show on your question, the more effort will the community do in order to answer it.